# Extracting numpy array slice from numpy.argmax results

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (3,3) numpy array and would like to figure out the sign of the element whose absolute
value is maximum:

```
X = [[-2.1,  2,  3],
     [ 1, -6.1,  5],
     [ 0,  1,  1]]

s = numpy.argmax(numpy.abs(X),axis=0)
```

gives me the indices of the elements that I need, `s = [ 0,1,1]`.

How can I use this array to extract the elements `[ -2.1, -6.1, 5]` to figure out their sign?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
# You might need to do this to get X as an ndarray (for example if X is a list)
X = numpy.asarray(X)

# Then you can simply do
X[s, [0, 1, 2]]

# Or more generally
X_argmax = X[s, numpy.arange(X.shape[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Use`sign` or `signbit`.

```
In [8]: x = numpy.array([-2.1, -6.1, 5])

In [9]: numpy.sign(x)
Out[9]: array([-1., -1.,  1.])

In [10]: numpy.signbit(x)
Out[10]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I was a more interested in extracting the actual elements - Bi Rico's answer. I knew I could use numpy.sign on the result. Thanks.